How does Roman Catholicism understand the Pope's statement that all religions are paths to God?

"All religions are paths to God. I will use an analogy, they are like different languages that express the divine.” - Pope Francis, Interreligious Meeting with Young People -
Address of His Holiness, “Catholic Junior College” (Singapore) Friday, 13 September 2024

In this address he also said, "There is only one God, and religions are like languages, paths to reach God. Some Sikh, some Muslim, some Hindu, some Christian. Understood?"
I am struggling to comprehend this sentiment in a positive Biblical light because it seems as though the Pope is clearly saying that worship of false gods is a pathway to the one true God.
Far from finding a biblical basis for this sentiment, I find nothing but the exact opposite.  Can we add Baal worship or any of the various pagan Corinthian gods and make the Pope's list any worse?
How does Roman Catholicism rescue the Pope from directly contradicting Jesus; "I am the way, the truth, and the life; No one comes to the Father but by me."?

Regardless if you receive an answer or not, no Catholic is obligated to defend Pope Francis statements in an non-ex-cathedra statement. Besides that Pope Francis is quite well known to make dubious and/or unclear pronouncements while at the same time not invoking papal authority. He is almost speaking like a real politician....

What the Pope probably meant was that all religions are manifestations of man’s longing and search for God. Because all people on earth have had implemented in their spirit an urge to grasp the meaning of life. Something which God, through Jesus, is the sole author and judge. (Rom 2:11-16)

This question can only currently generate debate and controversy. The pope should be more careful and not openly speak heresy to children. Pray for him.

@GratefulDisciple Good edit.  Thank you.

@MikeBorden You're welcome.  Talking about Sikhism and the pervasive Hindu polytheism culture in India, Christianity Today has an article today of a conversion of a Sikh 12th grader that includes a "testing of God" (that smacks off prosperity gospel), a miraculous experience involving John 14:6, but fortunately leading to genuine Christian fruits of peace, forgiveness, and joy followed by more spiritual experiences and growth despite opposition.

The Pope said:

There is only one God, and religions are like languages, paths to reach God. Some Sikh, some Muslim, some Hindu, some Christian. Understood?

His Holiness sets the baseline pretty low, adding Hindu to the list is kind of non-sensical since, even though there is a sense of a Creator God in Brahma in Hinduism, it's definitely a polytheistic religion which is in opposition to Sikhism on that point so he must have meant God (i.e. Jesus Christ), not Brahma.
One of the maligned documents of Vatican II is the document on other religions it states:

One is the community of all peoples, one their origin, for God made the whole human race to live over the face of the earth. One also is their final goal, God. His providence, His manifestations of goodness, His saving design extend to all men, until that time when the elect will be united in the Holy City, the city ablaze with the glory of God, where the nations will walk in His light.
Nostra Aetate - Vatican II

Which is a fancy way of saying what the Pope said. The idea that religions are like languages is that they are imperfect ways of expressing God and they are like paths, that they're human ways our bodies go from point A to point B.  The Catholic Church does not subscribe to an idea of the perspicuity of scripture.  We believe that we need the Holy Spirit to understand Revelation - both Scripture and Tradition.  Furthermore, we believe our understanding is marred by human frailty.  Human frailty comes in to play with both translating languages and walking paths. The pope said (prior to this statement) that he was making an analogy - so it is not right to treat "paths to reach God" as anything more than an analogy - which in itself, is an imperfect way to communicate truth, but what else could he say?
In soundbite land, the Pope made all religions equal, but in reality, he told a group representing an interfaith youth group that they've got work to do.

Good answer.  The setting of the address (during his recent Papal visit to Southeast Asia) is also important: Singapore is one of the most multicultural city in Asia, and has in the past decade became the launching pad of missionaries to the surrounding countries, so much so that the city earns the title "The Antioch of Asia", see this months's Christianity Today article, though for the present challenge.  Anyway, the setting made the Pope's way of finding common ground there is appropriate.

Quoting from catholic.com article on a question 'Is There Really “No Salvation Outside the Catholic Church?”' that quotes Catechism of the Catholic Church, paragraphs 846-48:

How are we to understand this affirmation, often repeated by the
Church Fathers? Re-formulated positively, it means that all salvation
comes from Christ the Head through the Church which is his Body:
“Basing itself on Scripture and Tradition, the Council teaches that
the Church, a pilgrim now on earth, is necessary for salvation: the
one Christ is the mediator and the way of salvation; he is present to
us in his body which is the Church. He himself explicitly asserted the
necessity of faith and Baptism, and thereby affirmed at the same time
the necessity of the Church which men enter through Baptism as through
a door. Hence they could not be saved who, knowing that the Catholic
Church was founded as necessary by God through Christ, would refuse
either to enter it or to remain in it” (CCC here quotes The Dogmatic
Constitution on the Church, “Lumen Gentium,” 14, from the documents of
Vatican II).

Article continues:

The Church is very clear here. There is no salvation apart from a
salvific union with the Catholic Church. However, the Catechism
continues:


This affirmation is not aimed at those who, through no fault of their
own, do not know Christ and his Church: “Those who, through no fault
of their own, do not know the Gospel of Christ or his Church, but who
nevertheless seek God with a sincere heart, and, moved by grace, try
in their actions to do his will as they know it through the dictates
of their conscience – those too may achieve eternal salvation”
(quoting, Lumen Gentium, 16).
“Although in ways known to himself God can lead those, who, through no
fault of their own, are ignorant of the Gospel, to that faith without
which it is impossible to please him, the Church still has the
obligation and also the sacred right to evangelize all men” (quoting
Ad Gentes, 7, another document from Vatican II).

and article concludes:

I recommend a careful reading of the texts represented by the
footnotes in paragraph 16 of Lumen Gentium (nos. 17 and 18) which
reference St. Thomas Aquinas’ Summa Theologica III q. 8 a. 3 ad 1, and
the Instruction of the Holy Office of Dec. 20, 1949, that I will
reference below. These make very clear that anyone who is ever saved
is not saved by his or her false religious beliefs (i.e. Judaism that
rejects Christ, Islam that denies Jesus is the Son of God, etc.);
rather, they can be saved in spite of them. If they are ignorant of
the truth through no fault of their own (they have never had the
opportunity to either hear or understand the truth), then the limited
amount of truth that they do have “among shadows and images,” and “all
goodness and truth found in these religions [serve] as ‘a preparation
for the Gospel and given by him who enlightens all men that they may
at length have life’” (CCC 843).

Also as Ken Graham commented "Pope Francis statements in an non-ex-cathedra statement" so Roman Catholics do not interpret it as official teaching. Roman Catholics should follow the Catechism of Catholic Church

I don't see how this addresses the question, it simply did the same thing my question did. My answer focused on how the most prominent of the catholic church must be a good teacher, yours focuses on how the catholic teaching is in absolute opposition. And that the church would call it "not official teaching" even though it was "the Pope" at "the catholic junior college... how is that not in some way official?

@Wyrsa I would disagree, my question shows that while "There is no salvation apart from a salvific union with the Catholic Church" other religions can lead to God and that it is part of Catechism of Catholic Church. That is in agreement with what Pope said - how church understands it.

This is hard for me to understand.  Once one hears of Christ and the Church then Christ is the only salvation and can then be accepted unto salvation or rejected unto damnation but those who remain "ignorant through no fault of their own" may also achieve salvation?  Why would anyone evangelize such "ignorants" and put them at risk of eternal destruction through rejecting a Gospel of which they were previously safely ignorant?

@MikeBorden Feel free to ask a separate question. This looks like many questions that you have to answer for yourself. 1. Is all loving God going to save someone who never heard of Jesus and has no chance to hear about him (native americans before colonization) ?2. Do some people act by same moral standard as catholic would. ?3. Does knowing about Catholicism improve this moral standard. (when they did not follow it). ? 4. Is Catholic teaching truth. ? 5. Is salvation/damnation a binary option or are there for example levels of hell/heaven? Many questions come to mind ...

I don't know if this is (still) the norm in all countries, but when I was ordained, I had a small ceremony the day before where, in short and in my own words, I swore to accept with faith everything coming "from Rome", even if it wasn't ex cathedra. But that doesn't imply one has to accept anything the pope says without context. It does, I believe, imply I cannot just dismiss what he says, but I should accept it as a statement to consider, to try to understand in the context of official teaching.
If I do so, I think what the pope says can be understood in the light of what Piro quoted from the catechism. It is true, even as member of the clergy, I have no need to defend what the pope says, and neither do I have to follow it blindly. But it also isn't my place to judge it.
The matter raised by Mike Borden in the comments seems very relevant to me. Why would we teach the unknowing about Christ if they can be saved without that knowledge?
For one, they can be saved, but only under very strict conditions. If this would be a game of chance, your position would be very much better when baptized and in the Church.
But I think there is a second reason. We don't just tell people about Christ because we need salvation. We also try to tell people about Christ because we are so full of Him, because we have found an enormous treasure  in Him, and we want to share. Maybe that sounds trivial or childish, and maybe it is, but I think that is what truly drives a christian, and therefor also a catholic: all that love we receive from Christ is just forcing us to share it, it is a love that cannot be kept for ourselves.

From what I've heard, the answer is already quoted, but not emphasized enough.

This affirmation is not aimed at those who, through no fault of their own, do not know Christ and his Church: “Those who, through no fault of their own, do not know the Gospel of Christ or his Church, but who nevertheless seek God with a sincere heart, and, moved by grace, try in their actions to do his will as they know it through the dictates of their conscience – those too may achieve eternal salvation” (quoting, Lumen Gentium, 16).

Moved by grace that being of God.  Moved by the grace of God.
This "moved by grace" leads to actions that might save.  This is standard Roman Catholic teaching about how to be saved.  The Pope is simply asserting, clarifying what it has taught for some 2,000 years.

"This affirmation is not aimed at those who, through no fault of their own, do not know Christ and his Church".  Right, it's aimed at folks who profess Christianity or any other religion and declares they are on paths to God.  Can a Hindu be saved?  Certainly, but that doesn't make Hinduism a path to God.  Satanists can be saved too...if they leave the path they are on and take the narrow one.
